# why i am getting the mysql mode error in the group by clause even after changing its mode to full_group

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL:

```
SET @@global.sql_mode := replace(@@global.sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '');
SELECT m.dept_no, m.emp_no, d.dept_name
FROM dept_manager_dup m
LEFT JOIN department_dup d ON m.dept_no = d.dept_no
GROUP BY m.emp_no
ORDER BY m.dept_no;
```

and the error is:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'employees.m.dept_no' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Did you read the documentation about what [`only_full_group_by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) means? *"Reject queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns."* --- That mode is *specifically* what is causing the error. As you can see, the wording matches the error you get. So if you want non-standard `group by` handling, you need to **remove** `only_full_group_by`.

Comment: I have tired after removing it but still I getting error:    Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'employees.m.dept_no' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: *"this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"* means that mode `only_full_group_by` is **still in effect**, i.e. you didn't remove it. What are you even trying to do there? Since you don't do any aggregating, why use `group by`? Aren't `emp_no` unique for `dept_manager_dup`? Aren't `dept_no` unique for `department_dup`? If so, then there will be no duplicate result rows, and you should simply remove the `group by`, as it doesn't do anything except slow down the query execution time, making the database server group already distinct data.

Comment: ... and if `emp_no` is not unique for `dept_manager_dup` or `dept_no` is not unique for `department_dup`, then use `select distinct m.dept_no, m.emp_no, d.dept_name` and remove the `group by`. As I said, since you don't have any aggregated functions, the `group by` has no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [aggregation functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) for every column that is not in your `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT m.dept_no, MIN(m.emp_no), MAX(d.dept_name)
FROM dept_manager_dup m
LEFT JOIN department_dup d ON m.dept_no = d.dept_no
GROUP BY m.emp_no
ORDER BY m.dept_no;
```

There is the possibility to put all columns in the  `GROUP BY` like

```
SELECT m.dept_no, m.emp_no, d.dept_name
FROM dept_manager_dup m
LEFT JOIN department_dup d ON m.dept_no = d.dept_no
GROUP BY m.emp_no, m.emp_no, d.dept_name
ORDER BY m.dept_no;
```

And a further possibiliy is using [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.dept_no, m.emp_no, d.dept_name
FROM dept_manager_dup m
LEFT JOIN department_dup d ON m.dept_no = d.dept_no
ORDER BY m.dept_no;
```

Of course it depends on your wanted outcome, which function you can use, and sometimesyou have to test all to see the dieffrent results

Comment: Unless you remove sql_mode `only_full_group_by`.

Comment: Or not use any aggregated functions, like the question code doesn't, in which case changing to `select distinct m.dept_no, m.emp_no, d.dept_name` and removing the `group by` would be a better approach.

Comment: @Andreas removing is a bad idea, that only leads to sloppy programming and surely even more unwanted results.

Comment: *FYI:* Assuming `emp_no` is unique for `dept_manager_dup` and `dept_no` is unique for `department_dup`, all 3 statements have the exact same result.

Comment: Yes, without [mre] this covers most of the basics to get ti the wanted result

Answer (score 1):

You must *aggregate* all columns *not* listed  in the group by clause.

Try something like:

```
SELECT m.dept_no, m.emp_no, d.dept_name, count(*) as employee_count
FROM dept_manager_dup m
LEFT JOIN department_dup d ON m.dept_no = d.dept_no
GROUP BY m.dept_no, m.emp_no, d.dept_name
ORDER BY m.dept_no
```

or more convenient, you can simply code:

```
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Unless you remove sql_mode `only_full_group_by`.

Comment: Or not use any aggregated functions, like the question code doesn't, in which case changing to `select distinct m.dept_no, m.emp_no, d.dept_name` and removing the `group by` would be a better approach.